Why would solving #MATCHING(bipartite) problem efficiently solve #MATCHING efficiently?
Im gathering information about the matching counting problem for a graph $G$ (#MATCHING($G$)). I found that for the specific case of $G$ being a bipartite graph then the problem has a simple (not efficient) solution:
#MATCHING($G_{bipartite}$)$=perm(M(G_{bipartite})$)
where $M(G)$ is the adjacence matrix of the graph and perm($M$) is the permenent of the matrix $M$.
In the article i read this from, it says that solving the bipartite problem efficiently or equivalently solving the permanent of a matrix efficiently would mean that the general matching problem could be solved efficiently. This means that there has to exist a polynomial time algorithm that thransforms any given matching counting problem into a bipartite graph matching counting problem.
I thought that maybe given a graph $G=([2n],E)$ the matching counting problem for said graph could be solved by separating the problem into the $2nCn$ combinations of bipartite graphs that can be created with the vertices of $G$. However, this method isn't polynomial right? I'm new to these terms so I might be wrong there or there might be a different algorithm.
So my question is, why would solving the bipartite matching counting problem efficiently mean solving the matching counting problem efficiently?
Thanks for the help
P.D.: The article I read this on is this article in spanish "J.Andres Montoya. LA PERMANENTE COMPLEJIDAD DE LA PERMANENTE".

the figure in page 4 here shows the connection between permanent and bipartite matchings  https://dr.lib.iastate.edu/server/api/core/bitstreams/3bd53ae6-a7ba-459e-bd35-7781efd00145/content

@vallev in that link it shows how to relate the bipartite matching problem with the permanent. However, I have already solved that problem and what Im looking for is an answer for why solving the bipartite matching problem is equivalent to solving the general matching problem

I can't see how they would be equivalent

I guess that $perm(M(G_{bipartite})$ is equal to the number of perfect matchings of $G_{bipartite}$ rather than to the number of all matchings of $G_{bipartite}$.

I hope you don't expect this reduction to be practical. The existing proofs give us the following chain of reductions:

Reduce #MATCHING$(G)$ to #SAT$(F)$, where #SAT is counting satisfiability solutions.
Let's introduce a variable $x_e$ for every edge $e$. Then $F$ will consist of the following clauses: for every vertex $v$ and two its neighbors $u$ and $w$ clause $(\overline{x_{\{\,v, u\,\}}} \lor \overline{x_{\{\,v, w\,\}}})$ doesn't allow to include two adjacent edges into a matching. Now every satisfying solution of SAT$(F)$ corresponds to a matching in $G$ and vice versa, so #MATCHING$(G)$ reduced to #SAT$(F)$.

Reduce #SAT$(F)$ to $\mathrm{Perm}(A)$, where $\mathrm{Perm}$ is permanent. See The Complexity of Computing Permanent by L. G. Valiant. This is the most non-trivial step.

Reduce $\mathrm{Perm}(A)$ to #PM$(H)$ for a bipartite graph $H$, where #PM is counting perfect matchings. This step you already know as you mentioned in comments.


All reductions are polynomial.
